# Azure Web Deployment Fails - Website with given name already exists

Tags: azure, spring-boot, maven, deployment

When deploying my application I receive the following error:  **Website with given name azuredemo already exists**.

I am attempting to deploy a Java Spring Boot web application to Azure.  I created a Spring Boot application that works on my local machine against port 80.

I then ran `mvn azure-webapp:config` and configured the Application and then ran config a second time to configure the Runtime.

I get the following output from maven:

```
AppName : azuredemo
ResourceGroup : azuredemo-rg
Region : eastus
PricingTier : Basic_B1
OS : Linux
Java : Java 11
Web server stack: Tomcat 9.0
Deploy to slot : false
```

Then I ran the command `mvn azure-webapp:deploy` to deploy the application to Azure.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< demo:azuredemo >------------------
[INFO] Building azuredemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.12.0:deploy (default-cli) @ azuredemo ---
[WARNING] The POM for com.microsoft.azure.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01:azure-mgmt-insights:jar:1.0.0-beta is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/xxxxx/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/applicationinsights-core/2.6.1/applicationinsights-core-2.6.1.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Auth Type : AZURE_CLI, Auth Files : [C:\xxxxx\.azure\azureProfile.json, C:\xxxxx\.azure\accessTokens.json]
[INFO] Subscription : Pay-As-You-Go(yyyyyyyy)
[INFO] Target Web App doesn't exist. Creating a new one...
[INFO] Creating App Service Plan 'ServicePlandaaaa-aaa'...
[INFO] Successfully created App Service Plan.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30.596 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-03T15:02:13-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.12.0:deploy (default-cli) on project azuredemo: Website with given name azuredemo already exists.: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

So to troubleshoot the issue, I delete all of the Application Services.  I deleted all of the Resource Groups.  And attempted the deployment again to the same error.

I understand I am probably missing something, but going through the portal and dashboards, I cannot find what the conflict is.

**My Environment**

- Maven 3.6.3
- Java 11
- Spring Boot 2.3.8
- az cli 2.18.0
- Pay-As-You-Go subscription

**My Maven POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>azuredemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>azuredemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>3.1.0</azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <authType>azure_cli</authType>
                    <resourceGroup>azuredemo-rg</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>azuredemo</appName>
                    <pricingTier>B1</pricingTier>
                    <region>eastus</region>
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>Linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>Java 11</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>Tomcat 9.0</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of Azure App Services are required to be globally unique. Presumably, someone else has already created a web app with the name 'azuredemo'. Try making the name more unique and publishing again.

Comment: I added a unique prefix to the appName and this addressed my issue.  Thank you!

Comment: so it does not scope the name to be unique within your subscription? that feels so weird

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to update an app with a new deploy. If you get the error in this situation like I did, make sure that the **resource group name** matches the one that is already added in **azure**.