# How to modify the name of the webapp

Tags: safe-stack

The result of `dotnet run Azure` is the error "Website with given name SAFE already exists." I changed all strings in farmer-deploy.json containing "SAFE" to "SAFExyz" and saved my changes. I then rebuilt and then ran `dotnet run Azure` again. This resulted in exactly the same error message and the changes I made to farmer-deploy.json were reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the application in Azure App Services is required to be globally unique. Presumably, someone else has already created a webapp with the name 'SAFE' or 'SAFExyz'. Try making the name more unique such as adding a unique prefix and publish again.

See: [Azure Web Deployment Fails - Website with given name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034937/azure-web-deployment-fails-website-with-given-name-already-exists)

Comment: My misunderstanding was related to what exactly "globally unique" means. I erroneously thought it meant globally unique per Azure subscription.